# Loop through list based on items in separate sheet and add new lines

Tags: vba, excel

**Context**

I'm working at a production factory where we produce / machine metal parts, so we have several operations like sawing, milling, CNC turning, etc.

- Sheet `WData` contains a simple list containing item numbers and quantities.
- Sheet `WRouting` contains routings for the items in `WData` with multiple operations per routing. So every item in `WData` has one or more lines/operations in `WRouting`.

The idea is to build a macro which:

- Starts with the first item in `WData`.
- Loops through the routings in `WRouting`.
- When it finds the item it calculates how many operations this item has and adds the corresponding number of lines in `WData`
- Copies some additional information from `WRouting` into the new lines in `WData`.

So, if an item has 4 operations in `WRouting`, 3 new lines should be added to `WData`, below the first line of the item.

**Code**

My attempted code is below. It is extremely slow, eats a lot of resources and, when I insert a large list of items (i.e. 1000 items) it often crashes...

```
WData.Activate
MyRowData = 2
MyRowRouting = 2

WRouting.Activate
WRouting.Range("A1").Activate
WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Maakartikel  ", After:=ActiveCell, 
    LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
A = ActiveCell.Column + 1

WRouting.Activate
WRouting.Range("A1").Activate
WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Afdeling  ", After:=ActiveCell, 
    LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
R = ActiveCell.Column

WRouting.Range("A1").Activate
WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Machine  ", After:=ActiveCell, 
    LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
M = ActiveCell.Column

WRouting.Range("A1").Activate
WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Gemiddelde omsteltijd [min] ", 
    After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
S = ActiveCell.Column

WRouting.Range("A1").Activate
WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Cyclustijd [min]  ", After:=ActiveCell, 
    LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
C = ActiveCell.Column

Do
    If IsEmpty(WRouting.Cells(MyRowRouting, A)) Then 

        Do
            If IsEmpty(WData.Cells(MyRowData, 2)) Then 
            GoTo Door

            Else
            MyRowRouting = 2 
            MyRowData = MyRowData + 1 
            Exit Do

          End If
        Loop


    ElseIf WRouting.Cells(MyRowRouting, A) = WData.Cells(MyRowData, 2) Then 
        firstrow = MyRowRouting 
        Do
            If WRouting.Cells(MyRowRouting, A) = WData.Cells(MyRowData, 2) Then 
                 MyRowRouting = MyRowRouting + 1 
            Else
                Lastrow = MyRowRouting - 1 
                aantal = 0

                For I = firstrow To Lastrow
                    aantal = aantal + 1
                    If aantal > 1 Then
                        WData.Activate
                        WData.Rows(MyRowData + aantal - 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
                        WData.Rows(MyRowData).Copy
                        WData.Cells(MyRowData + aantal - 1, 1).Select
                        WData.Paste
                    End If                                

                    WData.Cells(MyRowData + aantal - 1, 7).Value = WRouting.Cells(I, R).Value                                
                    WData.Cells(MyRowData + aantal - 1, 8).Value = WRouting.Cells(I, M).Value                                
                    WData.Cells(MyRowData + aantal - 1, 9).Value = WRouting.Cells(I, S).Value                                
                    WData.Cells(MyRowData + aantal - 1, 10).Value = WRouting.Cells(I, C).Value                        
                Next I

                MyRowRouting = 2 
                MyRowData = MyRowData + (aantal - 1) + 1 
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    ElseIf IsEmpty(WData.Cells(MyRowData, 2)) Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        MyRowRouting = MyRowRouting + 1
    End If
Loop
```

I hope the code above makes sense, some variables are in Dutch which I hope is not too confusing.

**My main questions**

- How can I optimize this code so it runs at least stable?
- Is my logic and my usage of the VBA syntax correct?

Comment: Declare your variables, check you find something and drop the activates. E.g your second block should be replaced by `Set rA = WRouting.Range("A1:Z1").Find(What:="Maakartikel  ", MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) [new line]
If Not rA Is Nothing Then A = rA.Column + 1` where rA is declared as a range and A as Long. Alternatively, you could put your search terms and results in arrays and use a loop.

Comment: Just like @SJR said, dropping the `activates` will help you a bit, also you can prevent user from iterating your sheet with `Application.Interactive = False` and you don't need to show the update until it's finished with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (this will make it a little faster too).

Don't forget to turn them to `True` after finishing the process and show some notification to the user that it's done.

Comment: As an extension to what @Marco has suggested, setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` afterwards should speed things up too.